# Can VMD change its cartoon representation for secondary structure according to trajectories?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, visualization

I am using `VMD` to visualise the secondary structure of protein [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/).

The trajectories are from my Gromacs simulation. Firstly I use `File - New Molecule...` to load the `protein.gro` file. Secondly I use `File - Load Data into Molecule...` to load my `protein.xtc` trajectories.

Then I use `Cartoon` to visulise the structure. As I drag the time frames, all the secondary structures (e.g. alpha-helix, beta-sheet) stay the same. But I am pretty sure some of them are changing, as I look into the `Timeline` analysis for secondary structure.

So

1. how do I use `VMD` to see the secondary structures at different time frames?
2. Is there an alternative software that can do this?

Comment: Try here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. There's way more VMD questions there.

Comment: Can I move my questions there?

Comment: copy and paste them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a better fit for another community.